# Application Only for Tablets

Tags: android-manifest, android

I am create application only for tablets. Now i upload that application on market.
My application support in Android 2.2 Galaxy Tab 7 and All android 3.0 version Tablets.
Issues is that application can not install in mobile. when i use Android 2.2 version device and search my application than it's found and install in my device.

To avoid that i add this code in my manifest file:-

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" 
        android:normalScreens="false" 
            android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

but till that in mobile my application show.
I found some other code but this not show in my manifest file

```
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just check this Tutorial: http://goo.gl/HzTDB

Answer (score 2):

As I just answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540882/413127 it is possible

you need a combination of what you've outlined above in your Manifest:

```
 <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Comment: what about list of resolutions . and drawable ,layout folders to support this resolutions .

Comment: @ahmedShoeib something like this http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Comment: lett's say i need to develop android app for only tablets including SIII and Note what's the layout,drawable folders i should create. and what's is the standard resolution for each layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

`MinimumAPILevel` attribute in Manifest.xml is used to filter apps. Changes it accordingly.
If you want you app to be visible for only tablets then keep `MinimumAPILevel` greater than 9. If you want it be visible for phone also then keep `MinimumAPILevel` less than 9.

Comment: my minimumApilevel is <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
android 2.2 support in mobile and tablets both

Comment: @MiteshTechMe: Please let me know what exactly you are looking for. From your question I understand that you want your app to be for tablets only.

Comment: yes.. app only for tablets... galaxy tab 2.2 and other android tablets 3.0

Comment: Galaxy Tab running 2.2 is **NOT** a tablet, no matter how your dress it up