# I want my app to be installed only in tablet

Tags: android

I have an android application. I need to upload in the android market. I have developed this app in "Honeycomb".This app is only for android tablets. *I designed the layouts for tablets only (600x1024).*  I want this app to install only in tablets from android market and not in android phones. I really don't know how to do this..? Do i have to check programmatically..? if so, how to do that..? **My intention is that only tablets can install my app..! Please share your valuable suggestions..!**

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you try this -

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540882/940096). Have a good article from android developers page. [Support Screens Element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) and [Screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: This works for me.  I believe you want to update the `minSdkVersion` to 11 and `targetSdkVersion` to `16` now (although, the targetSdkVersion doesn't have to change. It will still be seen by JB devices).

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your manifest file.

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Look at here for more details.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two (good) ways to do this.

One way is to add some variables in the code

[Designing an android tablet-only app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540646/designing-an-android-tablet-only-app)

Pros:
-Easy to handle if there are new tablets

Cons:
-Maybe the app will shown to every device (but it's not installable for every device)

The other way is to restrict it in the Market

[How to restrict android app to specific device make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510649/how-to-restrict-android-app-to-specific-device-make)

Pros:
-Select every device you want or dont want

Cons:
-New devices will available so you have to update it

There are also some other ways and there is also another one. But i cant remember at this moment.

Hope could helpya
:)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you can definitely exclude phones/ small devices with this, but its worth a try: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html