# android:<supports-screens> Tag

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-play

I want my application to work on all Tablets, starting from for example Samsung Galaxy TAb 7 Inch up to any other tablet size.

When I published my app in the google play, It appeared on same handsets such as HTC Sensation XE and Samsung Galaxy S3!, here is my  tag in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I guess I don't understand exactly what does each child tag corresponds to which sizes excatly. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to support Galaxy Tab 7, the original version with Gingerbread, I'd say there might no way to support just Tablet under Gingerbread. Because Gingerbread doesn't distinct tablets and phones.

Only from Honeycomb, the smallest Width dp can be used to tell the difference of width.

So, I think this answer might help you:

[Designing an android tablet-only app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540646/designing-an-android-tablet-only-app/10540882#10540882)

Basically you need to add min SDK tag to restrict only Honeycomb(tablets only, no phones using honeycomb) and up can download your app

Comment: that's what I understood later on, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that those devices are considered largeScreen as stated here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

Have a look here to configure:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

I'd try setting largeScreen to false.