# How to disable support of app for Mobile phones and enable it for Tablet only

Tags: android, multiple-apk

How to disable support of applications for Mobile phones and enable it for Tablet only. I want to follow multiple apk files support. I also want to know that what should be the resource folder names for Tablet. Now, I've drawable-large for storing images and layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp for tablet.

Are these config. correct?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this code:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />



<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

for more read [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540646/designing-an-android-tablet-only-app)

Comment: and more description so please click this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540646/designing-an-android-tablet-only-app

Answer (score 1):

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

You can define this Suppport-screens tag inside Meanifeast file.. at there you can define your suitable screensize

and refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 1):

You can allow this in your manifestfiles with fillter of support screens 
 This can help youi to fillter  and runs only on tablets

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter for only tabs running ICS, add something like this in your AndroidManifest:

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

To get HoneyComb Tablets as well you simply change your minSdk

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Honeycomb and above will be supported. For specific folders to place layout files/drawables in etc check out:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html